# How to populate a dropdownlist using a stored procedure without an objectdatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

I am working on a web page that requires distinct user information to be displayed. several different users will be using this page, so the data will be different for each account.

This information is retrieved through stored procedures via entitymodel.

I cannot use an objectdatasource because my SP for the DDL requires an parameter(UserId) (unless there is a way to do it, in which I would not know !) The UserId is grabbed at page load via aspnet membership. this DDL also needs to be populated as the page opens up.
 I have done some research on programmatically populating a DDL but cannot find any examples that tailor to what I am trying to do.

I need a general DDL to be populated(item and value) by a SP with a parameter(userId), when the page opens up. 
Nothing more, nothing less :)

My question basically would be; what would be the best way to populate the dropdownlist under these circumstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post uses a Non-Typed-DataSet and a stored procedure to bind to a CheckBoxList which is the same principle (caveat: own blog post):

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/10/12/Bind-CheckBoxList-to-DataSet.aspx