# Render HTML from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I've got a SQL stored procedure that takes 2 parameters: one input, one output. The input would be from a drop down box, providing an index. The output is a `varchar(max)` that will contain html code (tables, images, links, text).

Essentially the purpose of this web page I'm trying to build is to display specific HTML code based on the results of clicking the drop down then executing the stored procedure.

So far in Visual Studio 2013 I've gotten the drop down to run the query to pull the values to pump into the SP ... and I have the SP defined in ASPX. But I can't figure how to get the SP to execute and populate the HTML somewhere - I was thinking it'd be a label?

I have: `ddlHTML_ID` is drop down list with

```
SqlDataSource = HTML_LOOKUP (pure query -- select * from tablename)
    (ID="ddlHTML_ID" runat="server"
     AutoPostBack="True"
     DataSourceID="HTML_LOOKUP"
     DataTextField="DROP_DOWN"
     DataValueField="HTML_LOOKUP_ID"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIndexChange")
```

The stored procedure:

```
SqlDataSource = sqlGetHTMLsp +
parameter 1 = ControlID="ddlHTML_ID" Name="lookupid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" + 
paramater 2 = ControlID="lblTest" DefaultValue="defaultValue" Direction="InputOutput" Name="combinedhtml" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"
```

`lblHTML` is a simple label.

Event on DDL change:

```
protected void ddlIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblHTML.Text = "changed"; //for testing
}
```

**update**

Sorry, I may not have stated this clearly enough ....
The drop down populates perfectly. What I'm trying to do is, once the drop down changes - take the value of the drop down and plug it into the stored procedure (parm 1). The sp will then return (parm2, as an input/output variable) a string which is HTML (the query in the sp connects several tables, so I figured it'd be easier to write is as an sp)

So, what I can't quite figure out is:

1.) how to get the sp to 'call' and

2.) how to get the result --

I've also tried playing with a string global, but I really think my main sticking is the sp.

**another update**

okay, I gave up on the sp, rewrote my query to return 3 columns with a WHERE on the drop down value @HTML_LOOKUP -- html header, body, footer (which is how the data is stored in tables), and figured out using a form & templates & being able to bind labels to data elements (which I didn't think was possible with just a free floating label)

AND **SHEBANG!!** it's freakin beautiful. so happy. thnx for your help.

Comment: I did try sqlGetHTMLsp.Update(); in the change event ... but that didn't help

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Too many people will hate you (and you'll arrive hating yourself) because this thing will be hard to maintain, reuse, ...

The best way would be to have as a result from your stored procedure a table containing 2 columns (usually a database identifier -the id- and a user friendly identifier -the name) and that one will be your drop down datasource:

```
select Id, Name from dbo.TableXYZ
```

Regarding the binding itself, see these links about how it should work:
[How to populate a dropdownlist using a stored procedure without an objectdatasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645255/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-using-a-stored-procedure-without-an-objectdatasou)
http://forums.asp.net/t/1792256.aspx?Bind+a+Drop+Down+List+from+store+procedure+in+ListView+

Remember/review the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.